# Emergency my waste is leaking over my back patio

Tags: sewer

The toilets make a gurgling sound and waste p
Spills out of an outside cleanout. Or at least thats what i think it is theres 2 beside each other. We have a septic tank and have well water system. Also rocks and sand in my cleanout

Comment: Sounds like a job for pros. Call a plumber and then a septic tank firm.

Comment: You have human waste oozing towards you, why are you asking a bunch of bozos on the Internet what to do? CALL A PLUMBER!

Answer (score 1):

Your septic system is full or u have a blockage, when the water level lowers to a point it will allow gravity to work again this is your Gurge sound from two pipes full of water, one way to self test is to put food coloring in toilet flush watch for die in septic tank to see if u can see it usually do it in morning before using any water for a min then do ur normal routen check again. If water is above the drain coming in tank which is approx 6" below riser on septic tank bottom. Try these steps first